# Erro ao rodar app React Native fora do modo debug

Tags: firebase, react-native, debug

Estou com um erro estranho que não consegui achar em lugar nenhum como resolver. Ao rodar o app no modo debug ele vai tranquilamente sem erros porém ao rodar o mesmo app sem alterações nenhuma com o modo debug desabilitado ele dá a tela vermelha de erro. Poderiam me ajudar?

Segue link do meu projeto no github: https://github.com/TcheORfabio/WhatsApp-Clone

PS: estou usando react-navigation ao invés do router-flux

PS2: Estou usando o genymotion como emulador para testar.

Print do erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá @Fábio. Edite a sua questão e coloque o código que achar necessário para se entender a sua questão e qual a sua dificuldade. Evite colocar apenas _links_ para o código ou colocar imagens. Aproveite para fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para melhor perceber como funciona o _site_.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se você ainda está com esse problema, mas eu resolvi assim:

```
$npm install --save firebase@4.9.1
```

voltando pra essa versão funcionou tranquilo.